# How do the Weeping Angels commute?

Tags: doctor-who, weeping-angels

How do the Weeping Angels commute?
The Weeping Angels must have "evolved" on some planet. But they manage to travel to planets such as Trenzalore and Earth.

How do they do this?
Do they build their own ships? Do they hitchhike always?

Comment: If they do build their own ships, they must have a very strict one-way system in place for walking down the corridors.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of individual Angels it would be difficult, but as a species it could be quite simple. In "The Time of Angels", The Doctor says "That which holds the image of an Angel becomes itself an Angel".
In essence, this means if that all images across the universe are either already a Weeping Angel, or at least have the potential to be, then all they need to rely on is others to spread their likeness around by creating more statues in their image - and people seem to love carving statues...

Answer (score 1):

The Angels have shown a considerable number of abilities and traits that would allow them to travel through space;

- On numerous occasions, Angels have shown the ability to **[teleport](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Blink)** their victims through space and time. There's certainly no obvious reason why (given that they don't need to breathe or eat) that they couldn't move *themselves* through interstellar space in the same way.
- They've shown a propensity to **hijack passing ships** including the "[Byzantium](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Byzantium_%28ship%29)" and the Tardis. They clearly have the intellectual capacity to pilot them.
- The non-canon "[Brilliant Book](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Brilliant_Book_2011)" has them invading human worlds by **travelling in "flocks"** through space. Unfortunately, no mode of travel is described but we can assume it's under their own power.
- Angels can project their "image" via television and radio signals from one place to another with the effect that **that image becomes an angel**. This would seem a highly efficient way to travel at light-speed.